# How to add tabs within tabs, Inner tabs using Bootstraps

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue regarding tabs within tabs. I am not using custom CSS. I am using bootstrap.
thanks a lot in advance.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a id="1" href="#">Tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="2" href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a id="3" href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tabContent" id="tabContent1">
         Tab Content 1
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs inertabs">
          <li class="active">
            <a id="11" href="#">T11</a>
          </li>
          <li><a id="12" href="#">T12</a></li>
          <li><a id="13" href="#">T13</a></li>
          <li><a id="14" href="#">WK</a></li>
          <li><a id="15" href="#">MND</a></li>
          <li><a id="16" href="#">YTD</a></li>
        </ul>


    <div class="tabContent1" id="tabContent111">
      Tab Content 11
    </div>
    <div class="tabContent1" id="tabContent112">
      Tab Content 12
    </div>
    <div class="tabContent1" id="tabContent113">
      Tab Content 13
    </div>


    </div>  



    <div class="tabContent" id="tabContent2">
      Tab Content 2
    </div>


    <div class="tabContent" id="tabContent3">
      Tab Content 3
    </div>  

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
        $('.nav a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).tab('show');
      
      var tabContent = '#tabContent' + this.id; 
      
      $('#tabContent1').hide();
      $('#tabContent2').hide();
      $('#tabContent3').hide();

      $(tabContent).show();
    })



        $('.inertabs a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).tab('show');
      
      var tabContent = '#tabContent' + this.id; 
      
      $('#tabContent11').hide();
      $('#tabContent12').hide();
      $('#tabContent13').hide();

      $(tabContent).show();
    })


</script>
```

[image]

As you can see I have done more than half of it.
When someone clicks on the tab tab1. Tab 2 and Tab 3 remain hides.
but when I click on the inert tab which is Tab11. It should work like the parent tabs.
and the parents tabs should not hide with it.

I will be very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="tab3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" role="tab" aria-controls="tab3" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane p-4 fade show active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1-1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1-1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1-2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1-2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="tab3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1-3" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1-3" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane p-4 fade show active" id="tab1-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab">content 1.1</div>
              <div class="tab-pane p-4 fade" id="tab1-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab">content 1.2</div>
              <div class="tab-pane p-4 fade" id="tab1-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab3-tab">content 1.3</div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane p-4 fade" id="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab">content 2</div>
      <div class="tab-pane p-4 fade" id="tab3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab3-tab">content 3</div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Berto99, I see it works fine. Can we remove padding etc.? like I want it in verticle align as you can see, there is padding in inner tabs.

Comment: @ALIKHAN i mean, remove the `p-4` in the code and there will be no padding